# Programmatically pack and publish NPM package with libnpm

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish

I'd like to publish to NPM within my CI/build system, so I found [libnpmpublish](https://github.com/npm/libnpmpublish) which seems to be the correct tool, but *explicitly states* that it doesn't pack your code into a tarball, although the `publish` API requires that you pass it a tarball (as compared to, say, a folder or a path).

Their suggested solution is

> Since `libnpmpublish` does not generate tarballs itself, one way to build your own tarball for publishing is to do npm pack in the directory you wish to pack. You can then `fs.createReadStream('my-proj-1.0.0.tgz'`) and pass that to `libnpmpublish`, along with `require('./package.json')`.

Is there a programmatic (in Node) way to script this process? I looked around the NPM repositories and couldn't find a package that  is dedicated to packaging, though I can find [this code](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/b80d650def417645d2525863e9f17af57a917b42/lib/pack.js) which seems to implement packing, but is in an archived repository- namely, it's *not* in `libnpm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can find is [npm-packlist](https://github.com/npm/npm-packlist) which, when given a folder, creates a list of files which can be forwarded to the NPM `tar` package, as demonstrated in the README for `npm-packlist`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack using the command line, but it works for a similar concept where I'm creating and uploading a package via a REST command.  I wrap in a promise that returns a stream so that I can easily add that to the formPost data:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`npm pack ${t}`, { cwd: d }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            reject(error);
        }
        var f = d + p.sep + stdout.trim();
        if (debug) console.log(`zip file "${f}" created.`);
        resolve(fs.createReadStream(f))
    });
});
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

there is now [`libnpmpack`](https://github.com/npm/libnpmpack), which will generate a tarball buffer in exactly the format that `libnpmpublish` expects, so this can be done with:

```js
const pack = require('libnpmpack')
const { publish } = require('libnpmpublish')

async function packAndPublish(packagePath) {
  // readPackageJson omitted for brevity
  const manifest = readPackageJson(packagePath)

  const tarball = await pack(packagePath)
  return publish(manifest, tarball)
}
```